# Upgrade to Elixir 1.7 in Ubuntu

Tags: elixir

I was trying to upgrade to elixir 1.7 (I currently have 1.6.0).
I ran `brew upgrade elixir` in my terminal but it said `Error: elixir not installed`.
And when I run `elixir --version` I'm getting this weird output:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 27-Jul-2018::15:03:35.806956 ===
        supervisor: {local,'Elixir.Logger.Supervisor'}
    errorContext: start_error
    reason: noproc
    offender: [{pid,undefined},
               {id,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler'},
               {mfargs,
                   {'Elixir.Logger.Watcher',start_link,
                       [{error_logger,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',
                            {true,false,500}}]}},
               {restart_type,permanent},
               {shutdown,5000},
               {child_type,worker}]
=CRASH REPORT==== 27-Jul-2018::15:03:35.806836 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: Elixir.Logger.Watcher:init/1
    pid: <0.88.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: noproc
      in function  gen:do_for_proc/2 (gen.erl, line 228)
      in call from gen_event:rpc/2 (gen_event.erl, line 239)
      in call from 'Elixir.Logger.Watcher':init/1 (lib/logger/watcher.ex, line 23)
      in call from gen_server:init_it/2 (gen_server.erl, line 374)
      in call from gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 342)
    ancestors: ['Elixir.Logger.Supervisor',<0.82.0>]
    message_queue_len: 0
    messages: []
```

(More crash reports here) ... and at the end:

```
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Elixir 1.6.0 (compiled with OTP 19)
```

I'm not sure what's going on, now I can't even run my elixir programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use system-wide version of Elixir by all means. There are many version managers like [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf), [`exenv`](https://github.com/mururu/exenv) and others to manage different Elixir versions on your computer. I would suggest using any of them.

Answering your question. I have no idea about `brew`, but it looks like you are to start with cleaning up your box.

1. downgrade Erlang to 20.0-
2. uninstall Elixir 1.6
3. upgrade Erlang to 21.0
4. install the latest Elixir (I still suggest to do it with version manager, since that way you might have many different versions coexisting which might be useful sooner or later.)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what’s causing the error, but try `brew reinstall elixir` if you have a corrupted installation.

Comment: I've found that ERLANG/OTP v.21 is not compatible with Elixir 1.6.0, that's the reason for the weird error. The question persists, how to upgrade to elixir 1.7?

Comment: homebrew just upgraded elixir to 1.7.1 which you can install with the usual commands (install, reinstall, or upgrade).

Comment: Reinstalling the latest elixir from Linuxbrew will be the easiest way to upgrade.